# How to set the build number in AppStoreRelease@1

Tags: ios, flutter, azure-pipelines, testflight

Is there a way to change the build name in AppStoreRelease@1 task? I couldn't find a way to increment it nor set a value. This is the task I've written in azure pipelines,

```
- task: AppStoreRelease@1
    displayName: 'Publish to the App Store TestFlight track'
    inputs:
      serviceEndpoint: 'Testflight upload'
      appIdentifier: 'com.sample.org'
      ipaPath: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.ipa'
      releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
      appType: 'iOS'
      shouldSkipWaitingForProcessing: true
      shouldSkipSubmission: true
```

Is there any attribute where I can set the build number? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes the build version we set using ios-bundle-version@1 task. So it will publish the build in testflight with the same version code.

Comment: How do we set up that task?  And what do we need to do to prepare the Xcode project file(s)?

Comment: @DavidReich which task do you want to know? Do you need to know the entire task list required for the test flight publication?

Comment: It would be nice to have an example of the ios-bundle-version task's parameters as they would appear in YAML. And what keys need to be in the plist file.  I'm using an Xcode 13 compatible project, so some keys are already in the project file, but Azure can't find them?

Comment: Hi @DavidReich, Actually I removed that task. If you use that task it will automatically increment your build id, but, it has some side effects specially it sets the build number of the pipeline in the info.plist.

Answer (score 2):

I added this to the yaml just before the `Xcode@5` task:

```
- task: ios-bundle-version@1
  inputs:
    sourcePath: 'Selfwealth/Info.plist'
    versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
    versionCode: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    versionCodeOffset: '1'
    versionName:
```

This results in a series of builds that have version #s like:

> 1.0 (10738)
> 1.0 (10744)
> 1.0 (10805)
> etc.

This is fine for us.  Devs can tell QA which build to use.  Which is our main need.

Comment: Hi have you been experiencing a strange error when uploading the ipa to the testflight from azure pipelines. Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74129232/an-exception-has-occurred-issuerid-is-required

Comment: And of course as soon as we upgrade to Xcode 14 this breaks.