# An exception has occurred: issuerId is required

Tags: ios, flutter, azure-pipelines, testflight, fastlane

I am trying to upload the ipa to the testflight using the azure pipelines. This was working fine before but all of a sudden I am receiving this error message,

```
 Transporter transfer failed.
2022-10-19T16:39:48.6038120Z [16:39:48]: 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.6165010Z [16:39:48]: There was a general exception while executing
2022-10-19T16:39:48.6281280Z An exception has occurred: issuerId is required
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8633660Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8634870Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8635950Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8637070Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8638180Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8638840Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8639930Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8640590Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8641980Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.bootstrap(BootstrapperPhase1.java:107)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8642810Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8643770Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.bootstrap(BootstrapperPhase1.java:78)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8644450Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8645760Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Launcher.launchBootstrapper(Launcher.java:37)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8647270Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8647950Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8648880Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8649580Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8650000Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8650600Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8650980Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8651490Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8651860Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8652710Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.start(Application.java:450)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8653110Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8654190Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter]  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.main(Application.java:947)
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8654600Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8655020Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter] 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8655260Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8656860Z [16:39:48]: [iTMSTransporter] [2022-10-19 16:39:48 UTC] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8657190Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8657650Z [16:39:48]: iTunes Transporter output above ^
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8658250Z [16:39:48]: There was a general exception while executing
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8659020Z An exception has occurred: issuerId is required
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8659710Z Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: There was a general exception while executing
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8660330Z \nAn exception has occurred: issuerId is required
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8661480Z The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8858100Z 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8859690Z [!] Error uploading ipa file: 
2022-10-19T16:39:48.8860530Z  
2022-10-19T16:39:48.9222620Z ##[error]Error: The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/fastlane' failed with exit code 1
```

Please note this was working fine before and nothing has been changed from the code or from the configuration level. Can anyone provide a direction on what was going wrong here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get this up and running by changing `vmImage` to `macOs-12`.

Change

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
  demands:
    - xcode
```

to

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: 'macOS-12'
  demands:
    - xcode
```

For a more detailed guide on this issue refer to:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20741